# Python Connection and Cursor base types or protocol

Tags: python, pyodbc, python-typing

I have a script that reads data from and Oracle database (using the oracledb package) and writes it to an SQL Server database (using pyodbc). I have a function that performs some query, that needs to run on both databases. This function accepts a Cursor as a parameter, and does its thing.

Now, the Oracle cursor is of type `oracledb.cursor.Cursor` and the pyodbc cursor is of type `pyodbc.Cursor`, even though they both provide pretty much the same interface. This means my function should accept an argument that is of either of these types. I would prefer *not* to specify all the potential cursors as types of the function's argument.

In ADO.NET there are interfaces such as `IDbConnection` and `IDbCommand` that are implemented by different database providers, and allow us to write provider agnostic code. Is there something similar with Python? Maybe a Python DB API [protocol](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/)?

Comment: Does `oracledb.cursor.Cursor` and `pyodbc.Cursor` say that they conform to some common API standard? If not, then you should bite the bullet and use a union. If you have your own types/globals/constants module, then you can just do `Cursor: typing.TypeAlias = oracledb.cursor.Cursor | pyodbc.Cursor` there once, use that type alias everywhere in your code, then add more to the union as you need more cursors.

Comment: They should both conform to the DB-API - at least that's what their documentaiton says

Comment: Unfortunately, the DB-API in the Python standard library doesn't have an abstract implementation - they're tied with the `sqlite3` implementation. What you can probably do is make your own DB-API out of the definitions in https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stdlib/sqlite3/dbapi2.pyi (standard based on https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/). Mostly this would just involve deleting code from the `.pyi` file and replacing base classes with `Protocols` or `abc.ABC` instead. The tricky part would be to handle exceptions; `oracledb` and `pyodbc` probably implement their own.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I just used a union type, and if I ever need a third provider - I'll add it to the union.